# How can I predict where matplotlib will draw ticks given some data?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Matplotlib does a good job of setting the limits and ticks on an axes to capture the range of the data while putting the ticks at nicely-spaced round numbers.

I'd like to be able to predict where ticks are going to get drawn for a set of data before it happens (actually, I'd be happy just knowing the limits of the ticks, I don't need to know specifically where the inner ticks will get drawn).

I've poked around the `Axes` and various `Ticker` objects, but I can't seem to find where this is happening. Ideally, I am looking for a function `automatic_ticker` such that if I have two vectors,

```
x, y = np.random.randn(2, 30)
```

I could call

```
xticks_predict = plt.automatic_ticker(x)
```

and then

```
plt.plot(x, y)
xticks_actual, _ = plt.xticks()

assert tuple(xticks_predict) == tuple(xticks_actual)
```

Does this exist?

Comment: Wouldn't automatic_ticker() just generate a plot, check the tick locations, and then delete the plot.  Have you already looked into  get_major_locator() / get_major_ticks() / get_majorticklocs() for this?

Comment: Well that's my current solution, but it a) feels like a hack and b) seems not to be totally robust, and fails at times in ways that are unpredictable. Surely there must be some calculation of ticks that is abstracted from drawing somewhere within matplotlib, I just can't find it in the codebase.

Comment: I am very curious how it fails - could you please expound upon that?

Comment: Sometimes the axis limits get stuck at (-0.05, 0.05) or something similar. I have not looked too closely into it, because I would rather just do it the right way than fix the hack solution.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for something like:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
xticks_predict = MaxNLocator(integer=True, symmetric=True).tick_values(x.min(), x.max())
```

But I saw some discrepancies in testing vs. the ticks used in plt.plot(x, y), most of which seem to be assymetric tick ranges about the origin --- even with `symmetric=True`.  The [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html) indicate `AutoLocator` as the typical default, but I found it to return fractional valued tick locations (e.g. `2.5`) when the ticks used in plt.plot() were all integral.

Of course, you could ``cheat'' by setting the plot ticks to the predicted ticks:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator

np.random.seed(seed=0)
x, y = np.random.randn(2, 30)
ticking = MaxNLocator(integer=True, symmetric=True)
xticks_predict = ticking.tick_values(x.min(), x.max())
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xticks(xticks_predict)
plt.savefig("example.pdf")
```